# Error when back button is clicked when using react router dom

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router-dom

I am working on an ionic react app when I click the back button after using history.push to navigate to a page as shown below

```
            history.push({
              pathname: '/mutiplequiz',
              state: 
                  { 
                      testUser,
                      testTime,
                      testSubjects
                  }
            })
```

on the Mutiplequiz page when I back button I get this error
[image]

here is the code on the mutiplequiz page

```
import React ,{useRef,useEffect,useState} from 'react';  
import { IonButtons, IonContent, IonHeader,IonIcon, IonMenuButton, IonTitle, IonToolbar,IonImg,IonButton,isPlatform, IonGrid,IonRow,IonCard,IonCardContent,IonCol, IonList,IonItem,IonLabel,IonListHeader, IonLoading, IonSpinner, IonAlert  } from '@ionic/react';
import { History, LocationState } from "history";
import { Link, useHistory, } from "react-router-dom";
export type historyData={
    testSubjects:[],
    year:number,
    testTime:number,
    testUser:string
}

const MutipleQuiz: React.FC = () => {

    const history: History<historyData>= useHistory();
    const { testSubjects,testTime,testUser }= history.location.state;
    useEffect( ()=>{
     
    },[]);
}

export default MutipleQuiz;
```

how do I go back without having this error

Comment: If you a few options. You can handle that the state isn't there with a warning message or redirect. You can move your state out of `history` and into your `App` or Redux. Or you can use only `history` transitions.